# Sync GIT with a server

Tags: git, synchronization, bitbucket

I use bitbucket as a GIT repo .. is there anyway to link it to my own server and sync files between them ? that whenever i change a file i push it to bitbucket and the changes will automatically be reflected in the server ?

Answer (score 2):

You can setup two remotes on your local repo, one for bitbucket and one for your server.  Then, just push to both repositories when you are ready to push upstream.  It takes two commands, but much easier than trying to develop some sync process when git is supposed to be distributed.  That way, if there are ever any merge conflicts between the two repositories, you can merge and commit the updates to keep them in sync.

```
git push bitbucket master
git push myserver master
```

Comment: Hey , Can you elaborate on how can i do so using a git client like source tree for example ? i'm new to git and i barely know how to use using command line

Comment: Remotes are basically pointers to different locations for upstream versions of your repo.  In SourceTree, right click the remotes header in the left column.  Click add remote.  Fill in the info for your bitbucket repo and then add another remote for your own server.  You will then see the option to push to either of these remotes when you click the push button in source tree.  However, I would suggest that you learn the command line tools as you will almost certainly need them during merging, rebasing, or some other task down the road.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to make a cronjob that pull from your server.

There are some other way but they are some more complicated. You build a Git hook and write some script they to such things over SSH for example. Or you could use [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/) to deploy your files.

Answer (score -1):

I found this project helpful for a similar need we had:

https://bitbucket.org/alixandru/bitbucket-sync

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Your answer is what we call “link only”. Such short answers that only rely on off-site resources are not the primary target of SO. Please consider elaborating more upon this, or your next, answer.